# Python3: Substitute variable in paramiko connect

Tags: json, python-3.x, iterator, python-3.6, paramiko

By using iter(), I am getting the hostname from a json file. And I am trying to forward hostname to paramiko connect, exec_command methods via a function call.

But while substituing hostname as variable, connect method treating it as hostname instead of variable.

How can I substitue variables in paramiko connect ?

```
import paramiko,json
def exec_commands(host_data):
 host_data = host_data
 new_client=paramiko.SSHClient()
 new_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
 new_client.connect(host_data,username='root',password='password',port=22,timeout=60)
 stdin, stdout, stderr = new_client.exec_command('uptime')
 for i in stdout:
    print(i)
 new_client.close()

with open('server_list.json','r') as f:
    server_list = json.load(f)


for item in server_list:
    print((item['mydev']))
    iterator_var = iter(item['mydev'])
    next(iterator_var)
    exec_commands(next(iterator_var))
```

And json file have content as below

```
[
    {
        "mydev" : ["192.168.56.101","192.168.56.101","192.168.56.101"]
    }
]
```

Error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Personal\Python_code\Logs_Finder\authentication.py", line 30, in <module>
    exec_commands(next(iterator_var))
  File "D:\Personal\Python_code\Logs_Finder\authentication.py", line 16, in exec_commands  new_client.connect(host_data,username='root',password='password',port=22,timeout=60)
  File "C:\Users\rgenupula\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 310, in connect
    retry_on_signal(lambda: sock.connect(addr))
  File "C:\Users\rgenupula\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\util.py", line 276, in retry_on_signal
    return function()
  File "C:\Users\rgenupula\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 310, in <lambda>
    retry_on_signal(lambda: sock.connect(addr))
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
[Finished in 26.4s]
```

## Working if literal IP Address has passed as argument.

```
import paramiko,json

client=paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect('192.168.56.102',port=22,username='root',password='password',timeout=60)
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('uptime')
for i in stdout:
    print(i)
client.close()
```

Comment: *"treating it as hostname instead of variable."* => What does that mean?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, Thanks for responding. Actually `host-data` is a variable   and it containes IPAddress from mydev dict dataset. But paramiko connect assuming `host-data` as hostname and trying to resolve.

Comment: Why do think so? What error do you get?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, Please check updated question.

Comment: I do not see anything in your updated question that would suggest that Paramiko is trying to resolve a hostname. + We need [mcve] => Do you get the same problem if you pass a literal IP address string to `new_client.connect`? + Can you connect to the same IP address using any SSH client running on the same machine as your code? Show us its log file.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, Yes. Please check question for code related to latest query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your code, it does not even make it to `exec_commands`. Your `next`calls make a little sense to me.

This works just fine:

```
for item in server_list:
    for item2 in item['mydev']:
        exec_commands(item2)
```